# Error:Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

Can anybody advise on the below error message. Never came across such an error message before with xcode.

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please post the output from the build log.